# Dúvida no código em calculo de probabilidade

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma calculadora para estimar a probabilidade de acertos em loteria.

Estou utilizando esta fórmula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo:

- **a** é o número de dezenas do volante (na Mega-sena, a = 60)
- **b** é o número de dezenas sorteadas (na Mega-sena, b = 6)
- **k** é o número de dezenas por volante (na Mega-sena se o nosso volante tem 6
  dezenas, k = 6)
- **i** total de números que se deve acertar para ganhar tal prêmio (para a sena, i = 6, para a quina, i = 5 e para a quadra, i = 4)

Explicado, vamos ao PHP. Fiz o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$k = $_POST['k'];
$i = $_POST['i'];

// Realizando as subtrações
$c1 = $a - $k;
$c2 = $b - $i;

// Calculo para Ca-k,b-i
$calculo_1 = gmp_fact($c1) / (gmp_fact($c2) * gmp_fact(($c1 - $c2)));
// Calculo para Ck,i
$calculo_2 = gmp_fact($k) / (gmp_fact($i) * gmp_fact(($k - $i)));
// Calculo para Ca,b
$calculo_3 = gmp_fact($a) / (gmp_fact($k) * gmp_fact(($a - $k)));
// Multiplicação de Ca-k,b-i com Ck,i
$calculo_4 = $calculo_1 * $calculo_2;

// Simplificando
$calculo_final_cima = $calculo_4 / $calculo_4;
$calculo_final_baixo = $calculo_3 / $calculo_4;


echo "Probabilidade de acerto " . $calculo_final_cima . " em " . $calculo_final_baixo;
?>
```

As contas batem quando `$k` recebe os valores padrões das loterias (Mega-sena: 6, Lotofácil: 15, Quina: 5 [...]), porém, se atribuo `$k = 7`, ficando:

```
// Exemplo da Mega Sena
$a = 60; // Números no total
$b = 6; // Dezenas que serão sorteadas
$k = 7; // Irei apostar com 7 números
$i = 6; // Acertos pretendidos
```

O resultado esperado seria (de acordo com a CEF): 1 em 7.151,980.

Mas estou tendo como retorno: 1 em 55.172,417.

Onde estou errando no processo?

Comment: Resolvi alterando `$calculo_3 = gmp_fact($a) / (gmp_fact($k) * gmp_fact(($a - $k)));` para `$calculo_3 = gmp_fact($a) / (gmp_fact($b) * gmp_fact(($a - $b)));`.

Comment: Coloque como uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Toda pergunta merece uma resposta.

Por definição C<sub>n,p</sub> `(combinações simples de n elementos distintos tomados p a p)` é igual a

```
    n!
_________
 p!(n-p)!
```

onde o sinal `!` significa fatorial. `(Fatorial de um número natural é o produto de todos os inteiros positivos menores ou iguais a ele)`.

Para `$calculo_1` e `$calculo_2` as substituições na formula foram feitas corretamente, porém não se sabe porque para o calculo de `$calculo_3` que envolvem as variáveis `$a` e `$b` você trocou `b` por `k`, você estava indo tão bem :)

```
    $a!
____________
 $b!($a-$b)!
```

portanto, em PHP, o correto para  `$calculo_3` é

```
                         gmp_fact($a)
              _____________________________________
              (gmp_fact($b) * gmp_fact(($a - $b)));
```

Comment: Perfeito Leo, eu dei uma viajada mesmo. Depois que refiz todo o cálculo na caneta mesmo fui perceber o erro. Valeu pela resposta!